# How to get drawable from imageview and convert to bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

I have create app which load picture from facebook. I use Picasso. Picasso will set image result to my Imageview. I want to get that image convert to bitmap.

Here is my Code to get Image from Facebook:

```
 URL imageURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large");                
 Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(imageURL.toString()).into(ImageView);
```

Here is my Code to get Image and convert to bitmap: (not work)

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ImageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70, true);
ImageViewTest.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

`ImageView.getDrawable()` always return null.

I need your help.
Thank you

Comment: Why not have Picasso just give you the bitmap when you retrieve it?

Comment: but i saw its parameter is imageview. your idea is convert imageview to bitmap ?

Comment: There are multiple options for what Picasso can do. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46082179/115145) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081082/115145).

Answer (score 1):

Does it seem like loading the image into the ImageView is working? What's probably happening is that you are calling ImageView.getDrawable() before Picasso has finished loading the image. When do you call the getDrawable code? Try doing something like:

```
Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(imageURL.toString())
  .into(ImageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess() {
          BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ImageView.getDrawable();
          ...
      }

      @Override
      public void onError() {

      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be inside an AsyncTask:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://....");
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but we need to use AsyncTask. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Picasso` API to accomplish what you are looking to do.

One option would be to provide a `Target` listener to perform the `Bitmap` manipulation before setting it on the `ImageView` like this:

```
Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
        .load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large")
        .into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                // Manipulate image and apply to ImageView
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        });
```

Or better yet, use `Picasso` to perfom the resize operation and do not do any `Bitmap` manipulation yourself, like so:

```
Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
        .load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large")
        .resize(70, 70)
        .into(ImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your imageview declaration
ImageView iv;
// Enable cache of imageview in oncreate
iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
// Get bitmap from iv
Bitmap bmap = iv.getDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the following code

```
 ImageView img;
 img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 Bitmap scaledBitmap = img.getDrawingCache();
```